# what does 런이고 나발이고 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

확실히 엄청난 비주얼. 런이고 나발이고 그런걸로 싸울게 아니라 일단 예쁨.

Answer (score 1):

1) 나발 trumpet

2) 기본 형태 (basic form) : A(=noun) 이고(or 고) 나발이고 B하자

At this time, absolutely B is rather than A.

3) 배고픈데, 커피보단 밥먹자

Because I am hungry, dinner is better than coffee.

배고픈데, 커피고 나발이고 밥먹자

Are you kidding ? Because I am hungry, dinner is better than coffee.

Or  Because I am hungry, it is absolutely nonsense that we consider coffee
 instead of dinner.

(Coffee is luxurious and novel, but here we need a practical thing)

reference :
http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000044833&supid=kku000057763#none